# SSIS Azure Connection Manager with SAS Connection String

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-storage

I normally use an account name and account key to create a connection to Azure Storage in SSIS.

Is it possible to use a SAS as a connection string for an Azure Connection Manager in SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use a SAS as a connection string for an Azure
>   Connection Manager in SSIS?

For now, it is **not** possible, enable an SSIS package to connect to an Azure storage account by using the values you specify for the properties: Storage Account Name and Account Key.